# Rename constraint reference that changed because of table rename

Tags: sql, oracle

I did some SQL to update a few things, and because of some constraint, I had to :

- Rename a table A into A_OLD.
- Create a table A (with some columns that A (now A_OLD) didn't have).
- Merge A_OLD into A.

But now I noticed i have an issue, because :

When I renamed A into A_OLD, it also changed any constraint on A into a constraint on A_OLD.
For example : 
`CONSTRAINT "FK_A" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_A") REFERENCES "A_OLD" ("ID_A") ENABLE`

But my A_OLD was just temporarry, what can I do in order to change any reference to A_OLD into a reference to A ?

Comment: The constraints are tied to the old table. You can't change a constraint to refer to a different table. You need to recreate the constraints for your replacement table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have add a "new" constraint.

Internally the database doesn't care about the name of things (much). Rather than using names for things, the metadata uses object references - and renaming an object doesn't change an object's ID, it just changes the external name of the object. That's why renaming a table causes all foreign keys to "automatically" refer to the new name of the table - the foreign key constraint still refers to the same object ID as it did before the rename. If you have now created a "new" table and want foreign keys to refer to the "new" table you'll need to create a new foreign key referencing the "new" table.